# how to disable bootstrap collapse

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have some FAQs in an accordion. Question 1 is active and open with the answer visible. Question 2, when I click on that, Question 2 closes. I don't want that. Ideally, and this is sort of off-top, I'd like Question 1 not to default to being opened.

I tried:

```
$(document).on('click', '[data-toggle=collapse] .fa', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

But my accordion still collapses when another is clicked on.

Comment: Can you show your HTML? Did you mean to say when you click Question 2, ***Question 1*** closes?

Comment: Yes, sorry that was a typo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your question, I can kind of guess your problem. Check to see if your HTML code has a `data-parent="xxxx"` attribute where xxxx is the id of the container. If you find it, remove that attribute. This is the thing that makes other panels collapse.

> To add accordion-like group management to a collapsible control, add
>   the data attribute data-parent="#selector". Refer to the demo to see
>   this in action.

See: https://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#via-data-attributes-3

Comment: Bingo, this was it, nice catch.

Answer (score 0):

The easy way to accomplish this would be to simply remove the div.panel-group container that wraps the accordion group. You could then also remove the "data-parent" data attribute from all the collapse targets, just for cleaning up the code.

And your second question -- to make a panel default to open, you just give it the classes "panel-collapse collapse in" <-- the 'in' makes the panel begin opened on the page.